# System.MissingMethodException in a dll when I shut down c# application

Tags: c#, dll, missingmethodexception

I found out about the error because I saw it in the windows built-in event viewer:

> Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
>   Exception Info: System.MissingMethodException
>   Stack:
>      at Injection.Main.DrawText_Hooked(...)

I have a c# application using easyhook. My dll critical code:

```
        public void Run(RemoteHooking.IContext InContext, String InChannelName)
    {
        // Install system hook to detect calls to DrawTextExW that is made by the client and call the function DrawText_Hooked when ever this happens
        try
        {
            DrawTextExHook = LocalHook.Create(LocalHook.GetProcAddress("user32.dll", "DrawTextExW"), new DDrawTextEx(DrawText_Hooked), this);
            DrawTextExHook.ThreadACL.SetExclusiveACL(new Int32[] { 0 });
        }....
```

And my delegate to handle the hooked function is:

```
        int DrawText_Hooked(...)
    {
            Interface.Read(hdc, lpString, cchText, dwDTFormat);

        return DrawTextExW(hdc, lpString, cchText, ref lprc, dwDTFormat, ref dparams);
    }
```

When I shut down my main application everything works fine unless I use `Interface.Read(...)`: in this case, the hooked application crashes. I've read it's probably because `Interface.Read(...)` doesn't exist anymore once I exit my app but I don't know how to tell my dll to stop doing that or simply unload so that it doesn't try to do `Interface.Read(...)` and finds out it doesn't actually exist anymore. How shall I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Two days looking for the answer and after posting it I discover it myself after 10':

What I did was to declare the hook static:

```
        static LocalHook DrawTextExHook;
```

So from my main code, on exit, I could call a static method that points it to `null`, therefore stopping calling my `Interface.Read(...)`.

```
        public static void stopIt()
    {
        DrawTextExHook = null;
    }
```